What enables/prevents changing language for a given application?
In theory, I can configure (via the system preferences) any application to run under a specific language (different from the default system langauge).
However, for some applications this option is disabled and macOS tells me, that the application ...

doesn't support additional languages.

e.g.:

So: How does macOS determine that an application supports additional languages or not?
I'm looking for a low-level explanation (beyond "contact the developers of the application to fix it"), as I am the developer of this specific application (which is cross platform, and my native OS is not macOS - hence my ignorance) and would like to add support for selecting languages.

It looks like Pure Data doesn't have internationalisation files. Those should reside in Resources directory and end with .lproj. Since PureData is not made with Apple native AppKit controls in order to make it work some additional code has to be written. When I've added Contents/Resources/pl.lproj directory into PD I'm able to select a language in Settings.app
Also here are some informations about localizations in macOS/iOS https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode/localization/

thanks that's valuable information. in the meantime, i also discovered that i could set the CFBundleLocalizations key in my Info.plist to list available translations.

Besides Mateusz's answer, I found that I could also provide a list of available translations explicitly via the CFBundleLocalizations key in my Info.plist.
e.g. adding the following to my Info.plist will make the languages "Azerbaijani", "Bulgarian" and "German" available in the System Settings:
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>az</string>
    <string>bg</string>
    <string>de</string>
</array>

